# Change text on hover and replace with original

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have a div that can be opened and closed using jQuery. The link text needs to change when hovered, so if the div is open the text will show "close" and vice versa. However, I can't figure out how to return the link text to its original value on mouseout (e.g. in the [example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZv6d/2/) the text should change back to Hello when not hovered).

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div>
     <h4>HELLO</h4>

    <p>Loads of interesting content etc</p>
    <p>Loads of interesting content etc</p>
    <p>Loads of interesting content etc</p>
    <p>Loads of interesting content etc</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("h4").click(function () {
    var par = $(this).parent();
    par.children("p").slideToggle(500);
    if (par.hasClass("closed")) {
        par.animate({
            height: 180
        }, 500);
    };
    if (!par.hasClass("closed")) {
        par.animate({
            height: 30
        }, 500);
    };
    par.toggleClass("closed");


    });

    $("h4").hover(
        function () {
             if ($(this).parent().hasClass("closed")) {
                  $(this).html("OPEN");
             } else {
                $(this).html("CLOSE");
             }
       },

function () {
    //how do I get back the original value on mouseout?
});
```

edit: solution I arrived at is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6hNpX/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html do this:

```
<h4><span class="ninja">CLOSE</span><span>OPEN</span></h4>
```

In your CSS do this:

```
.ninja { display:none; }
```

In your JS, do this on the hover (or better yet on('mouseenter,mouseleave') event

```
$(this).find('span').toggleClass('ninja');
```

That should get the desired effect.

My suggestion though is instead of using a hover event at all, when the click event fires, toggle the classes then.  That way it displays correctly all the time.

EDIT: On the .on() alternative (for mouse-enter, mouse-leave)

```
$('h4').on('mouseenter,mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('ninja');
});
```

EDIT EDIT otherwise you're going to have to have a .blur() event as well and that just seems like more code than is necessary here.  I suggest replace your .hover with the above .on and live happily ever after.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was after but pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I'd love to see the final result, if you feel like updating your code above.